# Spring encoding vista a controlador

Tags: java, spring, maven, utf-8

Tengo un problema al obtener caracteres especiales de un formulario desde un jsp, utilizo spring mvc version 5, con configuración java. Los caracteres especiales llegan al controlador de una forma no esperada ejemplo
ñ -> Ã±
í -> Ã­-

He querido establecer el encoding utf-8 especificando de la siguiente manera pero no he tenido resultados positivos

Agregando esta propiedad en el pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Esta otra al momento de compilar

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Mi configuracion en el WebMvcConfigurer

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "mx.com.dinamicdevs.reimpulsa")
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    registry.jsp().prefix("/WEB-INF/paginas/").suffix(".jsp");
}

public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/inicio");
}

public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

   // Register resource handler for CSS and JS
   registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/statics/")
         .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic());

   // Register resource handler for images
   registry.addResourceHandler("/imagenes/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/imagenes/")
         .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic());
}

@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public StandardServletMultipartResolver resolver() {
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}
}
```

En todos los jps tengo este tag

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

He probado agregando el siguiente fragmento en el web.xml

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Y agregando el filtro por default que proporciona spring security de la siguiente forma

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ConfiguracionSeguridad extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private SecurityHandler securityHandler;
    
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.headers()
        .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
        .and()
        .addFilterAfter(new CharacterEncodingFilter("UTF-8", true), SessionManagementFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/nodisponible")
        .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .successHandler(securityHandler)
        .and()
        .logout().permitAll();
}
}
```

Pero ninguna me ha funcionado, sigo recibiendo caracteres no esperados al ingresar los caracteres desde el jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Hola @EdgarGarcíaDávalos, prueba colocar un filtro a todas las peticiones de esta forma y forzar el encoding:

```
<filter>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>  
    <init-param>  
       <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
       <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <init-param>  
       <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>  
       <param-value>true</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Hola Roberto, ya lo intente colocando el filtro mediante la configuracion de java y tambien mediante un filtro personalizado.

Pero tampoco me funciono, cabe mencionar que le agregue un los para validar que si entraba al filtro.

El contenido era el siguiente:

`@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
     logger.warn("Filtrando cosas");
     request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
     chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }`